# Dojo - ReferenceError exception in promise being swallowed

Tags: exception, dojo, promise, deferred

In jQuery, if you make a mistake in your ajax callback method, you will get a proper console error message and stacktrace.

```
$.get("https://api.github.com/users/octocat/orgs", function() {
  var a = FAIL;
});
```

However, in dojo using dojo/request/xhr it seems these dumb mistakes are being swallowed completely. The only thing in my console when I run this is "then" and "always".

```
require(["dojo/request/xhr" ], function(xhr) {
    var promise = xhr.get("https://api.github.com/users/octocat/orgs");
    promise.then(function(data) {
        console.log('then');
        var a = FAIL;
        console.log('goodbye');
    }, function() {
        console.log('error');
    });
    promise.otherwise(function() {
        console.log('otherwise');
    });
    promise.always(function() {
        console.log('always');
    });
});
```

Using the deprecated dojo.xhrGet, the problem is very slightly improved. I get a console error message and my error handler is called but it only says "ReferenceError {}" and provides me with a stack trace that never points to a function I own:

```
dojo.xhrGet({
    url: "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/orgs",
    load: function() {
        console.log('dojo.xhrGet.load');
        var a = FAIL;

        console.log('goodbye dojo.xhrGet.load');
    },
    error: function() {
        console.log('dojo.xhrGet.error');
    },
    handle: function() {
        console.log('dojo.xhrGet.handle');
    }
});
```

When writing a program we make mistakes, it's nice that we have tools like chrome developer tools to point us to those mistakes. The time it takes to find an error when you can see a stacktrace and error message is obviously much quicker than if you get no feedback. I get no feedback in dojo, I can't believe that such a popular library could operate in this way. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The understanding of promises which you inherited from jQuery is fundamentally different to the one everyone else (check Promises/a+ implementations) has. For the rest of this answer I will talk about promises/a+ compliant promises. Dojo's Deferred actually isn't a+ compliant, but it's close enough that everything I discuss here applies equally well.

Promises are immutable, you cannot change a promises state by calling `then`. A promise represents an eventual value, it would be nonsensical to be able to change the promise by saying "once the value is ready, do this".

So then, hopefully that explains why your error handler is not invoked, but the basic idea, of catching errors, is still totally possible. You just need to use return values. When you call `then` on a promise, it returns a new and (almost always) different promise. This new promise is very special, if the original is resolved, and the success handler you passed is invoked, and that returns something, that something will be the resolution value of the second promise.

Equally, if the error handler (on the first promise) is triggered, and that function returns something, that something will be the resolution value of the second promise. The same is true for thrown errors, they are passed to the error handler (of the second promise!).

So here's your first code sample written in a more promises/a+ way :

```
require(["dojo/request/xhr" ], function(xhr) {
    var promise = xhr.get("https://api.github.com/users/octocat/orgs");
    promise.then(function(data) {
        console.log('then');
        var a = FAIL;
        console.log('goodbye');
    }, function() {
        console.log('error');
    }).then(null, function() {
        console.log('otherwise');
    });

    promise.always(function() {
        console.log('always');
    });
});
```

I don't really understand what you want to do with the always function, so I wasn't sure where to place that one. On the subject of call stacks, I would recommend checking out the Q promise library which has incredibly advanced asynchronous call stack support.

Comment: This is a great explanation of what's going on. Here's a slight change to your code that gives a stacktrace too: http://jsfiddle.net/5rHM6/ Unfortunately the stack trace doesn't point to the correct line (it points to the console.error line). So if you want to catch the error, this is the correct answer; if you want to find the error I'm inclined to pick my answer. However it seems that if you do catch the error the instrumentation gets suppressed so you can't get the best of both worlds.

Comment: You're right, it's more of a message passing service ("there was an error") as opposed to a full error throwing service with stack trace. I would urge you to check out the Q library, it's the best asynchronous library I know of and they certainly deal with this problem.

Answer (score 4):

In dojoConfig set useDeferredInstrumentation: true. Here's [an example](http://jsfiddle.net/gNdCb/2/).

```
        <script>
           var dojoConfig = {
                useDeferredInstrumentation: true
            };
        </script>
        <script src="js/lib/dojo/dojo.js.uncompressed.js"></script>
```

This gives a fairly functional error message and stacktrace output on console.error:

```
ReferenceError {} "ReferenceError: FAIL is not defined
    at http://fiddle.jshell.net/gNdCb/2/show/:25:17
    at signalListener (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.0/dojo/dojo.js.uncompressed.js:14205:21)
    at signalWaiting (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.0/dojo/dojo.js.uncompressed.js:14196:4)
    at resolve (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.0/dojo/dojo.js.uncompressed.js:14360:5)
    at signalDeferred (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.0/dojo/dojo.js.uncompressed.js:14249:15)
    at signalListener (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.0/dojo/dojo.js.uncompressed.js:14220:6)
    at signalWaiting (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.0/dojo/dojo.js.uncompressed.js:14196:4)
    at resolve (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.0/dojo/dojo.js.uncompressed.js:14360:5)
    at signalDeferred (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.0/dojo/dojo.js.uncompressed.js:14249:15)
    at signalListener (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.0/dojo/dojo.js.uncompressed.js:14226:4)
    ----------------------------------------
    rejected at signalDeferred (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.0/dojo/dojo.js.uncompressed.js:14252:15)
    at signalListener (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.0/dojo/dojo.js.uncompressed.js:14223:5)
    at signalWaiting (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.0/dojo/dojo.js.uncompressed.js:14196:4)
    at resolve (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.0/dojo/dojo.js.uncompressed.js:14360:5)
    at signalDeferred (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.0/dojo/dojo.js.uncompressed.js:14249:15)
    at signalListener (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.0/dojo/dojo.js.uncompressed.js:14220:6)
    at signalWaiting (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.0/dojo/dojo.js.uncompressed.js:14196:4)
    at resolve (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.0/dojo/dojo.js.uncompressed.js:14360:5)
    at signalDeferred (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.0/dojo/dojo.js.uncompressed.js:14249:15)
    at signalListener (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.0/dojo/dojo.js.uncompressed.js:14226:4)
    ----------------------------------------
Error
    at Promise.then.promise.then (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.0/dojo/dojo.js.uncompressed.js:14420:24)
    at http://fiddle.jshell.net/gNdCb/2/show/:23:13
    at runFactory (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.0/dojo/dojo.js.uncompressed.js:1117:43)
    at execModule (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.0/dojo/dojo.js.uncompressed.js:1245:5)
    at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.0/dojo/dojo.js.uncompressed.js:812:7
    at guardCheckComplete (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.0/dojo/dojo.js.uncompressed.js:1260:5)
    at contextRequire (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.0/dojo/dojo.js.uncompressed.js:811:6)
    at req (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.0/dojo/dojo.js.uncompressed.js:137:11)
    at http://fiddle.jshell.net/gNdCb/2/show/:21:1"
```

Comment: Of course it would be nice to be able to actually catch or handle these errors in something like window.onerror. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I had very specific needs in that I *needed* the exception to hit the native catch clause that the browser implements. Nevermind why I needed this, But I used something like this:

```
function scream(func) {
    return function() {
        var args = arguments;
        setTimeout(function(){
            func.apply(null, args);
        }, 0);
    };
}
```

Then, to use it

```
var promise = xhr.get("https://api.github.com/users/octocat/orgs");
promise.then(scream(function(data) {
    //do stuff
}));
```

By using setTimeout, you execute the function on the browsers event queue, making it impossible for dojo to swallow your exception. But, in general this is a bad solution because:

- it changes part of the stack trace
- it changes a part of your code which previous executed synchronously to asynchronously, which can change program behavior
- you can't chain multiple .then() promise objects to the return value, which is one of the really nice things about promises.

Anyway, I'm just presenting it as option.